# Which of these plural forms is the correct one?

Tags: grammatical-number

I want to describe a list of numbers where each entry is the numeric category of a word. For example, 'english' has category 1, 'love' has category 2, etc, so the list would be [1, 2, ...].

Is this list called 'word categories' or 'words category' or 'words categories' or 'word category'? Note that, this is for variable name in my program.

Thank you.

Comment: "word category" is the noun phrase here, so the plural of it is "word categories".

Comment: Why don't you make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"word category" is the noun phrase here, so the plural of it is **"word categories"**.